# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ASP.Net (MVC)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

Hello im kind new in MVC and i made a website so first i set a models and then from this model"with declaring the Db Context "  i create a Controller and view from that and when i view it in website form it use to work fine and i can create data in the data base but then when i create everything i want to add a foreign key between the tables so i went the table and i added it and update but there is an error shows up when ever i try to add new data into the table so what should i do i hope that someone help me out this is some pic of the error and the table 
[this is the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxZuz.png) 
[the foreign key in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yPXy.png)
the code that send the error

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,UserID,KickOffDate")] UseCase useCase)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.UseCase.Add(useCase);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(useCase);
        }
```

Comment: Update you question by adding your sourcecode to your question not using any hyperlinks.

Comment: Use Try Catch and tell us the inner exception message showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete your current migrations folder. (I trust you do not have any
   expensive data)
2. Change the name of your data table in the Config.Sys file.
3. Delete the table in App_Data
4. Then enable migrations.
5. Create a Add-Migration *somename* again
6. Then... Update-Data

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will solve with the migration. For migrate do the following:

Open **Package Manager Console**

```
Tools –> Library Package Manager –> Package Manager Console
```

Then use the following commands

```
PM> Enable-migrations

PM> Add-migration Example // You can give a name instead of "Example"

PM> Update-database
```

Comment: hello and thx for reply , will when ii tried to unable the migrations it gives me that i have 2 migration i need to enable 1 
with showing me this error so i tried to declare 1 of them but i didnt unable it 
`To enable migrations for 'websiteApp.Models.DBContaxt', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName websiteApp.Models.DBContaxt.
To enable migrations for 'websiteApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName websiteApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext.` 
also i tried to add it again it didnt work ....

Comment: The context type 'websiteApp.Models.DBContaxt.' was not found in the assembly 'websiteApp'.
 when ienable it it shows me this